# listview custom adapter item deselected on changing orientaion of screen

Tags: android, listview, screen-orientation, custom-adapter

I am using using listview with custom adapter, but the problem is when i select items which is radio buttons in radio group get deselected while changing the orientation of the screen. i want the selected item to be selected even if we change the orientation of the screen. here is my code,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterCallback {
    ListView listView;
    DataClass data;
    ArrayList<DataClass> arrayList;
    Button button;
    Adapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            data = new DataClass(i, "std " + i);
            arrayList.add(data);

        }


        adapter = new Adapter(this, arrayList, MainActivity.this);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


    @Override
    public void onMethodCallback(int pos, String name, String atten) {

    }
}
```

Adapter.java

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<DataClass> arrayList;
    private AdapterCallback mAdapterCallback;


    public Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<DataClass> arrayList, AdapterCallback callback) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.mAdapterCallback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final DataClass rowItem = (DataClass) getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView tv_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        tv_name.setText(rowItem.getName());

        final RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rdbt_group);
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, @IdRes int checkedId) {

                RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);

                if (null != checkedRadioButton && checkedId > -1) {

                }
            }
        });


        return convertView;
    }


}
```

list_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rdbt_group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_no"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="A"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_clr"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="B"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_yes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="C"
            android:textSize="15sp" />


    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please write an else case for if (null != checkedRadioButton && checkedId > -1) {  } and try again

Answer (score 0):

Every time screen rotates fragments and activities gets recreated. You've got to save State.
[See this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16990793)

Comment: ah, ok :) sry I'm new to this.

Comment: That's alright, we all have been there. Here is a link on how to do it properly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer